# Windows Mobile 6.5 MenuBar

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a Windows Mobile 6.5 Handheld device that is being used for a work related purpose. When a user uses their finger to either slide down or tap the top status bar (the area where the clock is), they can pull down a Menu Bar that has some preinstalled apps there. Such as battery, time, etc.

This function is similar to how Android has it's notifications located at the top of the phone.

I would like to disable this feature through a registry change or XML file. I do not want to disable SIP, the start menu button, or hide the status bar, but instead only disable this pull down feature.

Does anybody know what registry key or XML file that would turn off this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the taskbar, it will still be there and update the clock etc, but the user can not click it.

To do so do a HWND hWnd=FindWindow("HHTaskbar",NULL) and then use EnableWindow(hWnd, FALSE);

See http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/05/29/windows-mobile-kiosk-mode-series-part-2/ for a sample code.

Comment: You'll have to bare with me, I am new to this and I appreciate the help. On the code, if I grab his sample code underneath "Not full screen, taskbar locked", where would I want to drop the CS file on the handheld? Is it just a CAB file and placed in the Autoinstall?